# Sufficient & Necessary condition for integral positivity

Tags: calculus

Suppose given a real interval $\mathcal{I}$, a non-negative function $f(t)$ on $\mathcal{I}$ and some positive scalar $\alpha$, I'm trying to figure out the necessary and sufficient conditions on the scalar $\alpha$ so that

$\int_0^t f(\tau)(\alpha-f(\tau))d\tau \geq 0, \quad \forall t \in \mathcal{I}.$

The sufficient condition is obviously $\alpha \geq f(t)$, for all $t \in \mathcal{I}$. However, I am not sure about the necessary condition. Any references for this problem would be most helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Write it as $\alpha\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau)d\tau - \int_{0}^{t}f^2(\tau)d\tau\geq0$. Observe that $\int_{0}^{t}f^2(\tau)d\tau=0$ when $\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau)d\tau=0$.

Comment: Hi deyore, can you expand a bit more on your hint. I'm not sure I quite understand.

Comment: You can solve for $\alpha$ (when possible) $\alpha\geq \frac{\int_{0}^{t}f^2(\tau)d\tau}{\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau)d\tau}$. The other observation is the reason why in the cases in which you can't solve for $\alpha$ there is no problem, the inequality still holds.